# Best desoldering technique for reverse engineering, or maybe UART

Tags: uart, soldering, can, reverse-engineering, hacking

So I'm trying to play with an EPS motor. I was able to get it to this stage while still functioning (can bus still alive and motor spins), but I want to see what processor is uses and see if I can dump the firmware using UART.

I was able to locate the processor on the other side of the PCB using a borescope, there was two other blobs of thermal paste as well but could not tell what were under them.

It seems the only way to take it apart if to desolder the top header pins first to remove the connectors, then desolder the 40 pins on the sides and bottom. But this leaves me with the thermal paste which might be glue and possibly damage the processor in the process. But if I can identify it, then thats great. I would want to solder everything back together at some point, so the desoldering process has to be clean and reversible without spills.

Are the any UART pins visible that I might be missing, or how to even test them. That would be much better then going through the above.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: a schematic diagram would be better

Comment: You can almost guarantee that the software will be read protected.

Comment: Also firmware can be located on external memory.

Comment: ‘Uart pins’ if it were a wireless router then you might expect uart pins, but probably not for an automotive device. You’d hope a jtag interface over uart. Desoldering looks like it might work assuming you have a decent desoldering station, but as you’ve probably gathered, these things are not designed to be repaired. For loosening glue and epoxy, a heat gun is useful. Epoxy looses most of its strength by around 90degrees C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to see what processor is uses and see if I can dump the firmware using UART

That hasn't been a thing for well over 20 years unless some custom bootloader was implemented using UART. In which case they have few reasons to make it accessible to you. Furthermore, UART is in general is avoided in automotive applications.

Around year 2000s, all the old, horrible and unreliable MCU programming interfaces, including UART-based junk, were starting to get replaced by single wire debugging. Good riddance! At the same time, on-chip flash memories with copycat protection became standard. Meaning you can't read anything out of the MCU unless you erase it first.

The QR code suggests that this product is from the 2010 decade somewhere, which probably means that modern MCUs were used.

The Mitsubishi logo suggests automotive market, which is especially pedantic about copycat protection. It also means that the odds of finding a Renesas (former Mitsubishi) MCU on the board are pretty good. Which in turn means that you'll also either find a proprietary single-wire interface or a standardized SWD/JTAG interface. Either way, copycat protected.

The 2nd pic looks like a LQFP100 so that's very likely the MCU.

Comment: that's a Data Matrix code ... quick search indicates that it was invented in the early 1990's

Comment: @jsotola Fair enough, but still this looks like a modern PCB. The QFN part in the upper right looks like a CAN transceiver, given that pins 6 and 7 seem to go to a common mode EMI filter part and then a split termination. QFN were not common in the 1990s, more likely it is from 2010s.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks, it seems that RH850/P1M-E is the only chip that fits the criteria, specifically one of these 4. https://www.renesas.com/us/en/products/microcontrollers-microprocessors/rh850-automotive-mcus/rh850p1m-e-high-end-automotive-microcontrollers-electronic-power-steering-systems?field-type=QFP100&method-field-type=OR but no datasheets

I'll take a wild guess and say this https://www.renesas.com/us/en/products/automotive-products/automotive-power-management/automotive-rh850-power-ics/raa270005kfp-power-management-ic-pmic-automotive-rh850-mcus is one of the other thermal pasted chips.

Comment: @royjr I wouldn't assume anything about which MCU it is before viewing the print on the LQFP. In case it happens to be Renesas RH, they are modern MCUs and you won't be able to read out the executable from them.